# Can there be value types in dynamic languages?

Tags: programming-languages, type-systems, static, dynamic

A value type is one whose instances are themselves saved in variables. A reference type is a type whose instances are saved somewhere and variables only hold the addresses of the instances.

Some languages, such as Java, have both types. For example `String` is a reference type and `int` is a value type.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i; // allocates 4 bytes on the stack, to store an actual integer value
    String s; // allocates 8 bytes on the stack (on 64 bit systems) to store an address
}
```

This is possible in statically typed languages, because the type of `i` isn't going to change; so after allocating 4 bytes for it, we can put in it any integer value.

However, what if the type of `i` were dynamic? For example in Python, the following is possible:

```
def demonstrate():
    i = 20
    name = 'george'
    if input() == 'Make a string':
        i = 'hello'
    print('i is ' + i)
```

All Python types are reference types. However suppose Python's `int` were a value type (and `str` still a reference type), and as a result we would try to actually put the number `20` inside `i`. In the stack after `i`, we would place an 8 byte reference to `'george'`.

After that, we might want to change the value of `i` to `'hello'`. This means reallocating room for it in the stack, instead of the room we previously allocated for the number `20`.

My question is: is this possible (or practical)? Are there dynamic languages which support value types? If so, how?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)**

Comment: Look up the space allocation for a union in C. Values in Python (and [perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values)) are not simple memory locations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6158918

Comment: Well, obviously it's possible, the implementer would just use a value instead of a pointer to a value. You have to track the type of each variable anyway, so toggling between a value type and a reference type is no different from toggling between two reference types. That's really it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it’s possible, and in fact it’s common to “unbox” values of common types for performance reasons, usually with some form of “tagging” to indicate whether a value is boxed or unboxed.

The simplest possible representation is with one word for the type tag, and one word for the value or pointer, according to the tag.

```
enum Type { INTEGER, REFERENCE };

struct Value {
  Type type;
  union {
    uint64_t as_integer;
    Object *as_reference;
  } data;
};
```

But we can do better. For example, heap allocations in many systems are aligned to 8-byte boundaries, which means that the bottom 3 bits of any pointer (`(uintptr_t)p & 7`) are guaranteed to be 0. As such, we can use these bits to store the tag, and thus get unboxed representations of common types with only one word. Here’s one simple such design, for a 32-bit system:

```
(x & 7) == 0 => (x & ~7) is a pointer
(x & 7) == 1 => (x >> 3) is an integer
```

(This representation is used by OCaml, a statically typed language, to determine which values are references that need to be traced by the garbage collector.)

We could add up to 6 additional representations to this, for booleans and other common types we might wish to unbox, and a further 8 if we had a memory allocator that guaranteed 16-byte alignment.

In [pointer magic for efficient dynamic value representations](https://nikic.github.io/2012/02/02/Pointer-magic-for-efficient-dynamic-value-representations.html), Nikita Popov describes a system for embedding integers, booleans, and floating-point numbers in a single 64-bit word by making assumptions about the representation of floats ([IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)) and address spaces. A similar representation was used in Mozilla’s JägerMonkey JavaScript engine.

Comment: YARV (the most widely-used Ruby implementation) has `Fixnum`s (`Integer`s that fit into n-1 bit on an n-bit architecture) and flonums (`Float`s that fit into 62 bit on a 64-bit architecture) as immediate value types.

Answer (score 0):

> All Python types are reference types.

That is wrong. (Well, kind of.)

> However suppose Python's `int` were a value type

No need to suppose. It *is* a value type. (Well, kind of.)

To be precise, you can't tell whether it's a value type or a reference type. In Python, `int`s are immutable, and for immutable types it is impossible to tell whether they are value types or reference types, so `int`s might be either and you wouldn't know the difference. They are, however, implemented as value types in all Python implementations I know of, and the language in the Python doc/spec strongly suggests implementing them as value types.

Comment: What do you mean by value type?

Comment: It is not impossible to tell whether it's a value type, and indeed it isn't a value type in CPython. An `int` has a persistent identity accessible via `id()`. Check the `id` throughout various transformations and you'll see that e.g. assignment and parameter passing keeps the same `id` and something like `n + 1 - 1` will (for sufficiently large `n` that aren't interned) produce a separate object with a different `id` (i.e., the `id` is a real identity, rather than representing the integer's value).